# Why does jQuery's animate method not support the CSS "display" property, or other CSS properties?

Tags: jquery, css

```
 <div id="content">
 <div id="ev1" class="evnt_imgs"><img src="images/e1.jpg" /> </div>
 <div id="ev11" class="evnt_desc">this text is purely related to event</div></div>

$('#ev11').animate({height:'auto',width:'100%',borderRadius:'20px',display:'block'},600);
    ev11.style.margin="auto";
    ev11.style.background="#333";
    ev11.style.display="block";
}
```

For more clarity over the question posted check the url http://bhaswara2k13.com/events.php

Comment: use opacity for fading in and out with .animate. As for why? probably because display is not a floating value. It's block, none, inline, etc. What's to animate?

Comment: Thanks Kai Qing!
Sorry for this foolish Qn. I started to develop websites before i could actually understand the usage of jQuery in particular context.
and Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To animate fading in and out and display there is a special method in jQuery. Probably because the display property itself can only have a certain set of values, which are not numeric.

Here is what to do:

```
$('#myItem').show(2000);
```

And to hide it:

```
$('#myItem').hide(2000);
```

Comment: And that works without jQuery UI? Here I was thinking it was `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` ?

Comment: Looks like the "fade" part is jQuery UI specific, but the rest should work. So I fixed my post. See jQuery doc: http://api.jquery.com/show/